# Placeholder display if value = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is it possible to still display the placeholder text IF the value is equal to the minimum value?

For this code

```
<input type="number" class="normal form-control no-padding ta-right" id="spreadThisTotal" min="0" value="0" placeholder="Amount to be allocated"/>
```

Can this be done with just html5? Or would this manipulation really have to be done with javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: If the value of 0 still will be a valid option, this will confuse the users a lot, so why should it behave like that?

Comment: I have to agree. I just opted to have it behave differently as to not confuse the users. Was just really more curious if this was possible without Javascript

Answer (score 1):

I believe some manipulation is needed here is a javascript solution

If the user clicks on the input box and the min value is current, then it adds the placeholder.

If the user key in the value, it triggers a click

```js
    function func(e) {
      if(e.target.value==e.target.getAttribute("min")){
      e.target.value="";
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("spreadThisTotal").addEventListener('click', func);
    document.getElementById("spreadThisTotal").addEventListener('keyup', function(e){e.target.click()})
```

```html
    <input type="number" class="normal form-control no-padding ta-right" id="spreadThisTotal" min="0" value="0" placeholder="Amount to be allocated" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below solution:

```js
document.getElementById('spreadThisTotal').addEventListener('keyup', checkValue);
function checkValue(event){
  if(event.target.value == 0){
    document.getElementById('spreadThisTotal').value = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="normal form-control no-padding ta-right" id="spreadThisTotal" min="0" value="0" placeholder="Amount to be allocated"/>
```